# difference between navigationBar.isHidden and setNavigationBarHidden

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have view controller which I am pushing from a view controller where navigation bar is hidden. But I want to show the navigation bar in destination view controller.

I tried with this statement it was not showing navigationBar.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
```

I tried this statement it is working

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
```

I want to know what is difference?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Nope they are not the same,

`self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden`

is a getter property (it shows you wheather the navBar is hidden or not.) It will just return a boolean value conveying the state of the NavBar weather it is hidden or not.
(try assigning its value to bool like `var isHidden = self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden` it will give you true of false according to state to the NavBar.)

whereas 
`self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)`

is a setter propety which gives you the provision of setting the state of the navBar.

Compiler does not throw any error on `self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false`
but will not do anything as you can only know the state from here.

Comment: `isNavigationBarHidden` is both a setter and a getter. `setNavigationBarHidden` is a setter only, and allows you to set if the bar is animated or not. `isNavigationBarHidden = true` and `setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)` are treated as identical by Swift.
Furthermore, the question asked about `navigationBar.isHidden`, which I am discovering gives you different results, depending on where it is used.

Answer (score 11):

`.isHidden` and `setNavigationBarHidden()` have different effects and outcomes. We won't be talking about the animated part.

The property of `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden` is an extension from `UIView`. The `isHidden` property belongs to `UIView` that means that `navigationBar` (which extends `UIView`) had done some overriding in `isHidden` causing it to have different effect and outcome compared to `setNavigationBarHidden()`.

Example for `setNavigationBarHidden(true)`:

[image]

where the navigationBar won't be transparent and page 1 (page with navigationBar hidden).

Example for .isHidden = true:

[image]

where the navigationBar is fully transparent and page 1 is displayed under page 2's navigationBar. Number 3 is the UIWindow.

Comment: I was wondering to which VC you're applying the change, then I saw the code is on the image itself ‍♂️

Answer (score 5):

Effect is exactly the same, but when using second version (method) you can also define animation.

When you are doing it via property - animation is off by default.

On top of that you have another option:

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
```

More on that topic here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621850-isnavigationbarhidden

> If true, the navigation bar is hidden. The default value is false. Setting this property changes the visibility of the navigation bar without animating the changes. If you want to animate the change, use the setNavigationBarHidden(_:animated:)method instead.

Comment: if both methods does the same why this statement self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
is not showing the navigationBar.

Comment: @santhosh - If you were able to understand the difference in the below given answer by me, then please mark it as a right answer.
Thanks.