# hide navigation bar in iOS13 + xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios13, xcode11

I want to hide the `navigationBar` for the first `ViewController` which is my first screen. It's all embedded within a navigation controller. I tried the below code but not working.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let navigationBarAppearence = UINavigationBarAppearance()

            navigationBarAppearence.shadowColor = .clear
            navigationBar?.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearence
            navigationBar?.standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearence
            navigationBar?.compactAppearance = navigationBarAppearence
            navigationBar?.backgroundColor = .clear
            navigationBar?.isHidden = true
        } else {
            navigationBar?.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

[image]

I'm using xcode11 How can I hide the navigation bar? Suggestions are always appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

try this code

```
 self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: thanks, Vishnu anilKumar, but can you explain the difference?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47470145/difference-between-navigationbar-ishidden-and-setnavigationbarhidden

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

instead of

```
let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar
navigationBar?.isHidden = true
```

Comment: thanks, Faysal Ahmed, but can you explain the difference?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47470145/difference-between-navigationbar-ishidden-and-setnavigationbarhidden

Answer (score 1):

Use ViewController's viewDidLayoutSubviews method to hide/show the navigationbar.

FirstViewController

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    }
```

SocondViewController

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know you tried with coding but try something different.
Without code, you can use Main.storyboard.

1.Press on your "Navigation Controller Scene"
2.Press "Navigation Controller"
3.Your side bar to your righthand side (forgot what its called)
4.Hover over the top icons to find "show the Attributes inspector"
5.After find under the "Simulated Metric" is the "Navigation Controller"
6.Next to "Bar Visbilty" unclick "Shows Navigation Bar"
7.All done

I know it is not code but hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

hide navigation bar for  in iOS15 + xcode 13

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

```
    if #available(iOS 15, *) {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 125/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }
```

Comment: Add this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide in each view controller. This code can help you.

```
// Hide navBar when view controller appear
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

// Show navBar again when view controller disappear
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```

> Note: You need to display the navBar again when disappear, because if
> you set this setting in one view controller, all other view
> controllers will be affected.

Tested with XCode Version 13.3.1 (13E500a) and iOS 15.1 (19B74) on iPhone 6s.